# Implementing fast refresh for better performance

Tags: oracle11g

In my present db implementation, my db does not has any data/table. All the data it gets is from other sources using dblinks and then populate an MV. This MV in actual being used by my db to serve customer requests. To implement this have created a simple view like this,

```
CREATE View vw_Get_Data
AS
SELECT 
FROM Table1@sourceDbLink t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2@sourceDbLink t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3@sourceDbLink t3 ON t2.id = t3.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table4@sourceDbLink t4 ON t3.id = t4.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table5@sourceDbLink t5 ON t4.id = t5.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN vw_Local vw1 ON t1.id = vw1.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN vw_Source2 vw2 ON vw1.id = vw2.id
```

Now we are using this view to populate materialized view and below is the code for the same,

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW schema.mv_Get_Data
BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH COMPLETE ON DEMAND
DISABLE QUERY REWRITE
AS
SELECT * FROM vw_Get_Data;
```

This MV is scheduled to be refreshed once every 24 hours and takes approx. 20 mins to get refreshed completely.

Now we have been asked to increase the refresh frequency and to do so we are thinking to implementing MV with FAST refresh. To do so we have implemented MV Log tables in the source db table and created MV with fast refresh for each table to create exact replica locally in my DB. Since we have 5 source table and hence created 5 MV log table at source db and also 5 corresponding MV with Fast refresh option. And then implemented a simple view on top of these Fast refreshed MVs and the populated the final MV which is being used by application. Below is the code of the new implementation.
Sample of one MV with FAST refresh,

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV1
BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH FAST ON DEMAND
WITH PRIMARY KEY
AS
SELECT * FROM Table1@sourceDbLink;
```

Code sample of new simple view,

```
CREATE View vw_New_Get_Data
AS
SELECT 
FROM Table1@sourceDb t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN MV1 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN MV2 t3 ON t2.id = t3.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN MV3 t4 ON t3.id = t4.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN MV4  ON t4.id = t5.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN vw_Local vw1 ON t1.id = vw1.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN vw_Source2 vw2 ON vw1.id = vw2.id;
```

Please find below the code of new MV,

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW schema.New_mv_Get_Data
BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH COMPLETE ON DEMAND
DISABLE QUERY REWRITE
AS
SELECT * FROM vw_New_Get_Data;
```

Then created scheduled job to executed this MV on demand. My main concern here is PERFORMANCE. i.e. In our previous implementation also we were joining data from all the sources in a simple view and then populated final MV using that simple view.

Also in our new implementation we are running MV with Fast refresh only to replicate the source table locally, later we are again joining these Fast refreshed MVs in simple view which is then used to populate final MV.

My main concern here is Performance because in my initial test i have not got any significant performance improvement. Also we have tried with Indexes. As join impacting the performance as the final MV is being refreshed COMPLETE and all the time it is joining the Fast refreshed MVs. Each source table/MVs are of 3 Million records.

Request you to please suggest if there is any better way we can improve the performance of this new requirement as business is asking this to get refreshed in every 45 mins instead of once in 24 hours and only a single refresh takes 20 mins.

Comment: And your code works? With `LEFT OUTER JIOIN`?

Comment: Hi @mathguy, yes code is working as expected. But the only issue is with performance. Business is expecting this MV to be refreshed in less then 5 mins but in actual its taking minimum of 20 mins. Also the data after joins is more than 10 million, I have also tried with indexes but have not got any significant results. Seeking for any alternative of doing real time refresh. ie if any transaction happens in remote(source) table then it should be reflected in local db real time.

Comment: Corrected the typo in code.

Comment: Hello friends, any suggestion on this issue would really be helpful and appreciated :)